# how much money it takes for a day without including accommodation In Uk

Tags: visa-refusals

My question is
1 -Why it's my low to calculate what I spend each month and not on my salary
2- how much you need for a holiday in Uk knowing that my brother who will host me

3- to get an estimate how many meters per day are needed[image][image]

Comment: Maybe you could add which city you plan to stay in. It should be around GBP 50/day I think, but probably depends on the location also.

Comment: @Thameur What do you mean by ‘meters per day’? The UK doesn’t specify a particular amount per day. It depends on your itinerary and planned activities eg travel costs while in the UK, entry fees to museums, attractions, historic locations etc. If you’re staying with your family outside of London £30-£50 per day should be ample, in London you’d maybe want to spend more. Most importantly, the total cost of your trip needs to be commensurate with your income - the ECO will likely find it hard to believe that someone would spend several times their monthly income on a visit lasting just one week.

Comment: excuse me but I earn 65000 DZD by me (420 £) I do not know why he calculated me low of what I spend for living costs 15 000 DZD (100£)

Comment: Where and how did you apply? The questions do not quite match those on the official website, some of the answers seem to be missing (your salary), weird ("car" instead of an amount), in strange currencies (euros instead of GBP or DZD)...

Comment: thank you for your answer you can detail me any question knowing that my salary is 65000 DZD money of (Algiers).   thank you for your valuable answer another question The cost to you personally of trip: 600£ The total amount of money for you? Costs of the airplane: £ 270 The cost of accommodation: My brother The cost of living expenses:?

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn’t that your expenses are too high, it’s that your salary is too low and/or your financials don’t make sense.

**Expenditures**: £1150 or about US$1500 for a one week vacation is within reason even if you have housing costs covered but it’s on the high side for visiting family. Let’s say you reduce it to £600 or about US$900, flight included.

**Income:** according to your own statements, you’re only spending about £100 a month on current expenses and made calculations based on that. The immigration officer seems to have missed that your salary is 65,000 DZD or about £420 GBP per month. I missed that too. You just posted your income/expenses worksheet and it’s a huge mess. No wonder the ECO couldn’t evaluate your financials properly.

Note that if your expenses are £100 and your salary is £420 per month, then your bank statements should show you saving about £3840 per year. Even if you’re giving another £150 per month to family, you should be saving around £170 per month or £2040 per year.

**What can you do:** Show that your income isn’t as modest as the immigration officer thinks and that your savings are sufficient given that you should be saving £2000-3800 a year. Plan a more modest vacation where you’re only spending a month and a half salary (£600) for everything including airfare.

Note: don’t think of doing funds parking or faking paystubs or bank statements  to make it seem like you’re richer than you are. Some unscrupulous travel agents will recommend doing this but it’s a quick way to an entry ban. If you can’t afford it, you can’t afford it.

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer another question The cost to you personally of trip: 600£ 

The total amount of money for you?

Costs of the airplane: £ 270

The cost of accommodation: My brother
The cost of living expenses:?

Comment: If you're staying with your brother, the cost of your accommodation is zero. The question you need to answer is simply "How much money am I going to spend while I'm in the UK?"